# A very difficult export. How to export a single table's content from the backup as a CSV postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, export-to-csv, database-backups, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin to load the backup into memory, but it is very slow due to the size of the backup. Also I have to use PostgreSQL server to restore data.

I have lots of ~10GB compressed backups and they require to restore ~7h each, then I use an sql query to export all data from one table as a CSV.

How can I export the data from the dump file as a csv?

Comment: You can't use SQL Server to restore a Postgres backup.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have to. I use PostgreSQL Portable. If you mean that SQL server is not PostgreSQL, then my apologize

Comment: The term "SQL Server" is usually associated with the database product from Microsoft.

Comment: If you just want to dump a table to csv do `copy my_table to '/var/tmp/myfile.csv' csv header`

Comment: @Hambone the problem is that the table is in the .backup file

Comment: Is the backup file in the Postgres "custom" format, or in (compressed) SQL? This makes a big difference to what options you can use with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).